# Should I upgrade my RAM or SSD?

Tags: windows-10, memory, ssd, upgrade

Laptop: Dell Inspiron 15 5567, 8 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD, Intel 7th Gen processor

What should I upgrade for better performance, my RAM or SSD? How do I know what to upgrade?

I need my computer for:

1. Mainly programming in Python, I use PyCharm.
2. Streaming on Discord.
3. Opening multiple tabs while I am learning to program.
4. Web surfing, Reddit, YouTube, watching movies, downloading torrents etc.

What should I upgrade first? RAM or SSD?

How do I decide that?

This is my realistic workload in my PC. What should I do?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIyDD.jpg

Comment: This is off topic.

Comment: It appears that your current RAM capacity is inadequate for your usage, so RAM would be a worthwhile upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

A **SSD** will speed up: system startup, program start, caching, copying, file saving, virus scan, any disk operation whatsoever. It will dimminish any waiting time you have at least by a factor of 10.

You report a Ram use of about 80%. Which means you still have some overhead, and with **a Ram upgrade** your system will only gain speed when you have a lot of tabs and windows open, and need to switch between applications. But for example, if you launch a new application while some disk operation is going on, this will be still dead slow.

A second argument could be:
Nowadays virtually all new laptops come with an SSD. But still most consumer systems come with 8GB of RAM. You see 16GB of Ram for multimedia / gaming / high end office PC's, and still more RAM for high-performance PCs.
So the sweet spot between price and performance today lies with 8GB Ram and SSD.

Go for the SSD.